# Calculate the difference of every registered value and the average of every 5th registered value with VBA

Tags: vba, average, array-difference

I continuously need to evaluate sets of raw data (1-1000 rows, 3 columns) in 5-15 sheets every time.

For two of the columns I have written a code that helps me take the average of every 5th value (every 5th row) adjusted to the number of rows by a reoccurring text value at the bottom. I want to calculate the residual of every raw value, in steps of 5, to the average within that range.

[This is a screen shot out of the data set and the average calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeehB.png)

It would be easy to calculate the residual for every row if the average was printed out on every row, and then do the residual calculation, but I can't figure out how and that is what I need help with.

Here is my code so far

```
Dim i As Integer

rownum = Range(ToCellB.Address).Row 'This is a reference to cell at the bottom at which the average function should end

For i = 23 To rownum Step 5
  ActiveSheet.Range("L" & i).Value = _
   (ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 1).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 2).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 3).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 4).Value) / 5

  ActiveSheet.Range("M" & i).Value = _
   (ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 1).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 2).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 3).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 4).Value) / 5

Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Range` object can contain more than one cell, and if this is the case, assigning a value to it assigns the value to the whole range.

Use

```
Dim i As Integer

rownum = Range(ToCellB.Address).Row

For i = 23 To rownum Step 5
  ActiveSheet.Range("L" & i & ":L" & i + 4).Value = _
   (ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 1).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 2).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 3).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 4).Value) / 5

  ActiveSheet.Range("M" & i & ":M" & i + 4).Value = _
   (ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 1).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 2).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 3).Value + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 4).Value) / 5

Next i
```

instead.

This create a range `Range("L23:L27")` for example, and then the entire range is populated with the local average.

Also, a call to the `value` property is implicit in VBA:

> The default member of Range forwards calls without parameters to Value. Thus, `someRange = someOtherRange` is equivalent to `someRange.Value = someOtherRange.Value`.

and can be dropped.

And `ToCellB` is already a range, and so you can just write:

```
Dim i As Integer

rownum = ToCellB.Row

For i = 23 To rownum Step 5
  ActiveSheet.Range("L" & i & ":L" & i + 4) = _
   (ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i) + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 1) + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 2) + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 3) + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 4)) / 5

  ActiveSheet.Range("M" & i & ":M" & i + 4) = _
   (ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i) + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 1) + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 2) + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 3) + _
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i + 4)) / 5

Next i
```

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value